# how to access class from embedded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, embed, instance, sprite

I am trying to get an instance of a specific class from an embedded swf, it so happens the class I need is also the Default Application extending Sprite for the swf.  I am able to do this successfully if I load the swf however I want to embed it instead.

The class I want to load is also extending a custom interface.  Here is what I have tried but is not working:

```
[Embed(source="resources/MySwf.swf")]
private var MySwf:Class;

private function someFunction() : void
{
    var inst:ISomeInterface = new MySwf() as ISomeInterface;
}
```

I appreciate any pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Docs for embedding are here:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html

You should be able to do something like:

```
[Embed(source='resources/MySwf.swf', symbol='TheExportNameInMyFlaLibrary')]
public var MySwf:Class;
```

Personally, I prefer to use the Flash IDE publish settings to be have Export as SWC checked.  That way, you can just drop the SWC into your FlashBuilder projects' lib folder and be done.  Don't have to worry about manually setting each class up like this.

Comment: I agree about swc's however in this particular case I am forced to use a swf.  I have tried the symbol tag as well but it tells me the symbol is not found when it clearly exists.  I do not have the class in a package, it is just in the root which may impact this?

Comment: The root should be fine; I don't ever include a package in my exports either.  Are you sure your symbol has the "Export for ActionScript" and "Export in frame 1" checkboxes checked in the Flash IDE?

Comment: I am using Flash Builder Pro and don't see those options anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific -- those options would be in the FLA that generated the SWF file.  Do you have access to that file?

Comment: I dont have an fla (as far as I can tell), there are only two files: .project and .actionScriptProperties that describe the project.  Since I can load the swf dynamically and access my class that way wouldn't that indicate its export properties are ok?

Comment: Nope!  Dynamically loading the SWF loads that SWF's classes into the application domain that you supply to the Loader instances' LoaderContext argument.  By default it gets put in your applications' domain.  After the SWF has been loaded in runtime you can get access to that class information through reflection if it's in the right domain, but that does not mean that the same SWF's class may be used as a static embed resource.